# How can I shortcut a slow conversion to CNF?

Tags: sympy, sat

I'm using sympy to generate expressions like this:

```
for crowd in itertools.combinations(symbs, max_true + 1):
    exprs.append(functools.reduce(operator.and_, crowd))
unaltered = ~functools.reduce(operator.or_, exprs)
```

Later, I convert them to CNF:

```
altered = sympy.logic.boolalg.to_cnf(unaltered, simplify=True, force=True)
```

It takes **a lot** of computer time.  I made a gist with more details:

https://gist.github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/501ea099826a5aeeacc9368710b059ec

Given that I'm generating expressions with for loops, they're in a reliable format.  Sympy (understandably) is doing the exhaustive thing and solving them "by hand", because it doesn't know that they're so well behaved. A human who is looking at the unaltered/altered expressions can easily ascertain the pattern and just generate the CNF directly with a for loop.

That's easy enough in this case, but I expect to have more constraints.

I want to know if I'm in uncharted terratory, or just failing to ask for help correctly.

Does Sympy have anything to help with this kind of thing?  Is there another library I should explore?  Is there a name for the "look at it and extrapolate based on a pattern" strategy that I'm proposing?  Is there a list of algorithms for the task somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure why sympy is so slow here but from what I see in the examples why not just apply de Morgan yourself? You can just negate the input symbols and then combine them  or/and rather than the other way round.

Comment: Thanks Oscar.  That's indeed what I plan to do, but "not more than sqrt(n) symbols true" is only the first constraint that I plan to apply.  As I introduce more complex constraints, I expect I'll want to lean on a library for the conversions--if one exists that will keep up.

Comment: I suggest opening an issue with sympy on github because I don't think it should be so slow. I'm sure that dedicated libraries for boolean algebra can be much faster for this operation. I expect it's also not hard to write your own code that uses sympy but does it much faster.

Comment: I tried it with boolean.py, which was similarly slow.  This post has me thinking that the conversion has a very large middle, (3125 terms for n=5) which I don't see because it simplifies away. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2554880